# iPhone file corruption

Tags: iphone, file, atomic, corruption, stdio

Is it possible (on iPhone/iPod Touch) for a file written like this:

```
if (FILE* file = fopen(filename, "wb")) {
    fwrite(buf, buf_size, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

to get corrupted, e.g. when app is forced to terminate?

From what I know fwrite should be an atomic operation, so when I write whole file with one instruction no corruption should occure. I could not find any information on the net that would say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since when `fwrite` is atomic? I can't find any references. Anyway, even if `fwrite` can be atomic, the time between `fopen` and `fwrite` is *not*, so if your app is forced to terminate between those times, you'll get an empty file.

As you're writing for iPhoneOS, you can use `-[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` to ensure the whole open-write-close procedure is atomic (it works by writing to a temporary file, then replace the original one.)

Comment: iPhoneOS derives from Mac OS X, Mac OS X is fully POSIX-compliant, and POSIX standard requires that C stdio FILE* operations are atomic.

However you are right that I can have corruption if fwrite won't be called after fopen. I'll have to check this.

Answer (score 1):

You could make things easier for yourself and write the data using the [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:) class that has a `writeToFile:atomically:` method waiting for you. Wrapping the raw buffer with `NSData` is not hard, there are the `dataWithBytes:length` or `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:` initializers.

Answer (score 1):

Data written with `fwrite` is buffered. So a sudden termination might not flush the buffers. `fclose` will flush the buffer but this does not implicate that the bytes are also written to the disk (due to OS level caches) AFAIK.

Comment: fclose will flush the buffer, am I wrong? And not flushing the buffer shouldn't corrupt the file.

Comment: fclose will indeed also flush the buffer.

Comment: @sfider: not flushing the buffer *will* corrupt the file. Example: assume the buffer is 512 bytes, and your data is 1200 bytes. fwrite would write the first 1024 bytes to disk, and leave the remaining 176 bytes in the buffer. Thus the file is incomplete and likely corrupt.